# quadTo in Android fingerpaint example

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view

I have a question about Android's "fingerpaint" example: https://github.com/Miserlou/Android-SDK-Samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.java. There's a detail I can't seem to understand.

On an "ACTION_MOVE" motion event, the view draws a new path segment to the canvas using the `Path.quadTo` method. This happens on line 104. If I understand correctly, the current position of the Path is `(mX, mY)`, and `(x, y)` is the location the user has moved the pointer to. So `quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2)` should draw a quadratic bezier from `(mX, mY)`, *halfway* to `(x, y)`, using `(mX, mY)` as the control point.

I'm not an expert on beziers, but since the control point is collinear with the start and end points, this looks like it should just draw a straight line, meaning that we might as well have just called `Path.lineTo` instead. Moreover, when I run the app and move the pointer, a line is drawn all the way to the new location, not just halfway as I would have expected from the code. Replacing `(x + mX)/2` and `(y + mY)/2` with `x` and `y` , or replacing `quadTo` with `lineTo`, doesn't produce a perceptible difference in behavior.

Can anyone help resolve my confusion?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the exact same question. After playing around a little with parameter values, what I understood is that:

1. Setting the control point coordinates to be the same as those of the starting point helps drawing a smoother curve.
2. 

> Moreover, when I run the app and move the pointer, a line is drawn all the way to the new location, not just halfway as I would have expected from the code

What happens is that each time a new path is drawn, the distance between start and end points is calculated in pixels. For every slight move a new path is drawn. So, in the end we have lots of small paths drawn one after the other. You're correct that the path (line, curve) seems to be drawn all the way to the end and not just halfway. However, what *actually* happens is that it is indeed drawn halfway; the distance between each new path is so small that we don't notice that. Let me explain this with the screenshots below. In both cases, I tried to draw from one side of the screen to the other.

This is how it looks when using the coordinates given in the sample code
[image: Paths drawn with coordinates as given in the example code]

And this is how it looks if we use the end point coordinates as the actual end point coordinates in quadTo()

[image: Paths drawn with coordinates matching the end point]

So, when we use the actual end point coordinates, the paths are more accurate in terms of where's the end point (notice how the end point to the right is more close to end of the screen in the 2nd photo?)

On the other side, the distance between start, control and end point plays part in the smoothness of the path. In the second screenshot, I used the halfway point as the control point and this resulted in less smooth paths.

At least that's what I have understood. If anyone has a more accurate explain, please share it.